# Difference between to live on and to live by

Tags: prepositions

My vocabulary trainer stands "to live on" and my vocabulary trainer says that it means that somebody does something to make one's living (by doing something).

> Example: I live on selling cars.

But I have also learned that "to live by" means exactly the same (and I have often heard sentences like "I'm living by selling cars").

Well, my question is: When should I use "to live by" and when "to live on"? Or is one of these prepositions wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [ODO](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/live):

> **live by**
> supply oneself with the means of subsistence:
> *they live by hunting and fishing*

*Live by* allows the description of the ***means*** of subsistence (such as selling cars).

*Live on* is followed by what you *have* to live, not what you *do*.

> **live off (or on)**
> • depend on as a source of income or support:
> *if you think you’re going to live off me for the rest of your life, you’re mistaken*
> • have (a particular amount of money) with which to buy food and other necessities:
> *how much money do you need to live on?*
> • subsist on (a particular type of food):
> *scavenging seabirds live off discarded fish and fish offal*
> • (of a person) eat, or seem to eat, only (a particular type of food):
> *she used to live on bacon and tomato sandwiches*

So...

> I live by selling cars
>
> I live on the money I get from selling cars